# Magento auto email send to user after place order

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento, email-confirmation

I am working on magento. How can I enable auto email send option after placing the order through the checkout process?

I just only want that when a user place the order from my site then an automatic email should be sent to the user email address which contain order details.

I used from sales->order->email sent process but need to do this process automatically after placing an order by the user.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The new order email is sent be Magento automatically - this is default system's configuration.

First of all, check that sending emails is not disabled. Go to admin panel to the "System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order" section. Verify there, that "Enabled" is set to "Yes".

If sending is enabled, then the application is needed to be debugged to find the actual reason. The easiest way is to setup [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and put a breakpoint to the start of `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()` method. Then you can execute PHP step by step till you reach the `$order->sendNewOrderEmail();` line. Make sure, that this line is executed. If it is not - find a reason, why, because it is a non-standard behaviour. If the line is executed, but email is not sent, the trace into this call to find the reason.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: One thing I want to get clear that does email send to user after payment done or before. I mean if payment is due and order is placed than confirmation email will go or not to user.

Comment: When I click on send mail in sales->order from backend then admin and user receives email confirmation of order.but I need to do it automatically.Any extension or any other method please elaborate your answer.

Comment: The email is sent after the order is placed. For orders with electronic payments it means, that email is sent after an authorization/capture request is performed to the payment processor. However, note that payment request is not performed for newer Magento versions (like 1.6+), if a redirect to 3rd party payment website occurs. That may be your case.